# How are built eigenvectors with lapack in C

Tags: c, lapack, eigenvector

I am working on eigenvectors with lapacke in C code and I was wondering how are they built when the the eigenvalue has a imaginary part? I mean I have to malloc on the same dimension as if they were only real, so how is the eigenvectors built?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If the matrix is real, double precision, finding the eigenvalues and eigenvectors for such a general matrix could be performed in C by using  `LAPACKE_dgeev()` from LAPACKE. LAPACKE is an interface to LAPACK. Hence, the [documentation about the](https://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/d9/d8e/group__double_g_eeigen_ga66e19253344358f5dee1e60502b9e96f.html#ga66e19253344358f5dee1e60502b9e96f) `dgeev()` function likely answers your question :

> If the j-th eigenvalue is real, then v(j) = VR(:,j),
> the j-th column of VR.
> If the j-th and (j+1)-st eigenvalues form a complex
> conjugate pair, then v(j) = VR(:,j) + i*VR(:,j+1) and
> v(j+1) = VR(:,j) - i*VR(:,j+1).

While the real and complex parts of eigenvalues are stored in two different arrays `WR` and `WI`, the eigenvectors, including those featuring a complex part, are completely stored in a real double precision array of size NxN. It is possible because the eigenvectors corresponding to a pair of complex conjugate eigenvalues are pointwise complex conjugate of one another.

An example showing how to handle complex eigenvectors found by `LAPACKE_dgeev()` is available in this [Intel code sample](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/docs/onemkl/code-samples-lapack/2022-1/lapacke-dgeev-example-c-row.html)

This interleaving technique is also featured in LAPACK `sgeev()` for single precision real general matrices.